# Crontab not recognizing editor

Tags: shell, cron

I made a script to be run on specific time each day. However, when trying to edit my crontab by running `crontab -e`, I get the following output:

```
crontab: no crontab for rpoddighe - using an empty one
crontab: /usr/local/bin/mvim -v -f: No such file or directory
crontab: "/usr/local/bin/mvim -v -f" exited with status 1
```

Running `echo $EDITOR` outputs the following, no surprise there:

```
/usr/local/bin/mvim -v -f
```

Furthermore, the editor works fine. Does anyone have any idea what might be going on? Please let me know if I need to clarify anything or add more details.

EDIT: I am using Zsh as my shell, in case that is of any relevance.

Comment: Just to check the obvious, what does `ls -l /usr/local/bin/mvim` return?

Comment: `lrwxr-xr-x  1 rpoddighe  admin  32 Aug 31 15:51 /usr/local/bin/mvim -> ../Cellar/macvim/7.4-77/bin/mvim`, so a symlink to the Homebrew-installed macvim.

Comment: It's probably failing to resolve the `..` in the linked path.  Can you replace that symlink with an absolute path?

Comment: Running `EDITOR='/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-77/bin/mvim -v -f' crontab -e` does not solve the issue.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of: Is `/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-77/bin/mvim` marked as executable?

Comment: It is, but I found the solution. It turned out that there was a discrepancy between the system vim and the one installed with Homebrew, and aliasing vim -> mvim -v -f was not the correct solution. After correctly symlinking vim to macvim everything works as expected. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that there was a discrepancy between the system vim and the one installed with Homebrew, and aliasing vim -> mvim -v -f was not the correct solution. After correctly symlinking vim to macvim everything works as expected.